# Crontab not properly executing a php file due to permissions

Tags: php, json, cron

I have a `version.php` script that writes over a `settings.json` file (CentOS6).

```
<?
$new['time'] = time();
file_put_contents('settings.json', json_encode($new, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
```

If I login via ssh and execute (with root):

```
php -q /www/cronjobs/version.php
```

everything runs fine and settings is updated properly. The idea for the php file is to be executed every 5 minutes with a cronjob, so I did this:

```
crontab -e
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /www/cronjobs/version.php >> /www/cronjobs/cron.log 2>&1
```

But after 5 minutes, the settings.json is not updated, and the cron.log is empty. How can I successfully add the cronjob to the crontab list? Perhaps it has something to do with permissions? I did everything with **root** and msversion.php, settings.json and cron.log are **755** chmoded.

Comment: What user do you want to execute this job?

Comment: @vgoff root is just fine. But it would be better to do it with the ftp user